# Xpath grabbing URL

Tags: php, xpath

Usually i get what I want with Xpath but this time I can't grab the url that I want. In this [page](https://www.31sumai.com/mfr/K1503/) there are a couple urls in  this `div` tag "btn-cont col-md-8 typesquare_tags" so I am trying to grab just one the  href which is this: `href="https://www.31sumai.com/mfr/K1503/outline.html"`

So I am using this code block but I couldn't reach it.

```
foreach($links as $href){
        $getContent = pageContent($href);
        $getXpath = new \DOMXPath($getContent);
        $Route = $getXpath->query("//div[@class='btn-cont col-md-8 typesquare_tags']/a[3]");
        foreach ($Route as $link3){
            $linkBOX[] = trim($link3->getAttribute('href'));
        }
    }
```

Do I missing something here?

PS. pageContent is a function which include DOMDoc/LoadHTML

Comment: Change `$link1` to `$link3`

Comment: oh sorry about the typo already changed it. But that didnt solve the problem.  :)

Comment: I can't find 'col-md-8 typesquare_tags' in the source html of that page

Comment: "btn-cont col-md-8 typesquare_tags" check this. it's there. @splash58

Comment: It's right. `typesquare_tags` is added after dom is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"typesquare_tags"` class name added dynamically. Try to locate `div` by first two class names:

```
"//div[@class='btn-cont col-md-8']/a[3]"
```

or

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'btn-cont') and  contains(@class, 'col-md-8')]/a[3]"
```

Comment: By the way could you, explain how did you figure it out. Because right now I am having the same problem at different website.

Comment: @Barbie You should check page source instead of checking HTML tree from rendered page, so instead of right click on element -> Inspect element, do right click on any place on page -> view page source -> Ctrl+F -> search for element

Comment: I got it, Thank you.